# How do I save a macro-enabled template in the startup folder in Word 2016 on a Mac?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, word-template

I’m having a problem with a macro I created—the macro is quite complex and is accessed through a user form (there are several options the users can select on the form). I created a macro-enabled template to send to beta testers, but all of the testers who use Word 2016 on a Mac are unable to install the template.

I thought this would be relatively straightforward for them to install and test, but apparently I was wrong. I’m on a PC, so I can’t test this directly myself, and I’m really struggling.

Can’t Mac users just install the template in their Startup folder? Where am I going wrong? Please help!

Also (and I don’t know if this makes a difference), I locked the macro with a password so the code can’t be changed.

Thank you!

Comment: ***[Create and use your own template in Office for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-use-your-own-template-in-office-for-mac-a1b72758-61a0-4215-80eb-165c6c4bed04)***

Answer (score -1):

VBA for **Mac** and **Windows** are similar but **not interchangeable**.

There are a substantial number of differences in how Word itself behaves between the two platforms, and in how VBA interacts with these platforms.

Ron de Bruin has started documenting the **[differences between VBA for Windows & Mac](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm)**.

Lots more information<sup>***†***</sup> online **[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=differences%20between%20Excel%20VBA%20Windows%20%20Mac)**.

<sup>***†***</sup><sub>Note that while some of the pages might seem to be specific to Excel, the core points and lists of property/method differences will be the same regardless of *which* MS Office product you're using.</sub>

---

**EDIT:** *More Info*

Here is another link that may be of use:

- MSDN : [Differentiate between Office for Mac versions at compile time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-mac-vba/macofficeversion)

...which generally explains how to specify which sections of code should run on which version of Excel VBA, using `#` pound signs and `MAC_OFFICE_VERSION`, like the example:

```
Sub VersionConditionals()
    #If MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 Then
        Debug.Print "We are running on Mac 15+"
    #Else
        Debug.Print "We are not running on Mac 15+"
    #End If
    #If Mac Then
        Debug.Print "We are running on a Mac"
    #Else
        Debug.Print "We are not running on a Mac"
    #End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but I’m specifically asking about Word, not Excel.

Comment: @DeniseFoster -  ***Both* of the links are relevant** and I'd suggest you review the list of differences between Mac VBA & Windows VBA.  For more people use VBA with Excel rather than Word, and far more people use VBA with Windows rather than Mac, so finding documentation titled specifically for Mac/Word/VBA would be tough.  Granted I used the word Excel when I meant Word in my answer but the answer is correct nonetheless: **VBA is not interchangeable between Windows and Mac.**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know VBA is not completely interchangeable between Windows and Mac. But is there a way for Mac users to install a macro-enabled template in their Startup folder like Windows users can?